# How accurate is the individual number covid-19 variant cases in each state?

Tags: covid-19, coronavirus, covid-19-datasets, united-states

How accurate is the individual number of covid-19 variant cases in each state?

[US COVID-19 Cases Caused by Variants](https://www.cdc.gov/coronavirus/2019-ncov/transmission/variant-cases.html)

I am trying to estimate the risk of being exposed to the one B.1.351 variant where the vaccine has been estimated to provide the least protection.

**Currently (check the link for updates) the incidence of B.1.351 (The South African variant) cases is 1.0% of all new cases.**

## Update:
Vaccine resistant South African Variant B.1.351 is doubling every month

The standard error of the proportion should provide a reliable estimate of the degree that the CDC numbers might be inaccurate. Current Genomic testing capacity is 9000 tests per week which is about 2% of the weekly case rate.

**I just found this much better data It has the current proportion of B.1.351 (and other) variant cases:**
[Variant Proportions in the U.S](https://www.cdc.gov/coronavirus/2019-ncov/cases-updates/variant-proportions.html)

It can be seen from the March 13 graph that the B.1.1.7 UK variant is dominant (59.6% of all recent cases).

Comment: If you're just asking about standard error of a proportion that's not really a medical science question, but you can see [this](https://online.stat.psu.edu/stat100/lesson/9/9.1) for instance.

Comment: @BrenBarn I am trying to estimate my risk of being exposed to the B.1.351 variant and need to know the exact degree of the reliability of the numbers provided by CDC. The CDC for example says that there are zero B.1.351 cases in my state. Could there really actually be 1,700 cases in my state?

Comment: You're not going to get any useful estimate when there are zero reported cases.  Beyond that, my understanding is that most places are only analyzing a minuscule proportion of cases to determine the specific strain.  The page you link shows a total of only 11,000 cases "caused by variants" although there have been more than 30 million COVID cases overall.  With that level of sparsity I'm doubtful that the available data would allow you to make a meaningful risk calculation.

Comment: @BrenBarn current testing capacity is 9000 cases per week which is a little more than 2% of the weekly US case rate. In theory if done properly this might provide an accurate estimate of the proportion of weekly variant cases.

Comment: @BryanKrause Even though I just received my second vaccine dose I was planning on remaining utterly isolated until herd immunity has been proven to be achieved. If my chance of coming in contact with the B.1.351 variant is nil I may stop isolating for a while and celibrate my birthday with friends and family.

Comment: @BryanKrause If the actual number of B.1.351 variant cases in my state is 1 instead of zero I will call this close enough.

Comment: @BryanKrause if we divide the total B.1.351 variant cases nation wide 288 by the total population 328,000,000 we get less than one person per million has a B.1.351 variant case. So it seems not much of a risk right now. If the CDC miscounted and there are actually 288,000 cases the risk is still quite low. In either case the risk of small gatherings is probably low enough.

Comment: @BryanKrause Yes we need the proportion of B.1.351 variant cases per per week as a proxy for the proportion of B.1.351 variant cases per weekly cases. From this we can extrapolate the total B.1.351 variant cases as a fraction of the total population assuming the probably false assumption that weekly cases equal weekly infections. In any case if our estimates are off by as much as three orders of magnitude fully vaccinated people (after two weeks) should be sufficiently safe from exposure to the B.1.351 variant at least for the immediate future.